# foreach PHP something wrong

Tags: php, html, foreach, content-management-system, contao

I have this code in PHP

```
<?php foreach($this->group('filter') as $i => $fields): ?>
        <?php $newField = $this->field('name#'.$i)->value(); ?>
        <?php $finalvar = explode(",", $newField); ?>
            <a data-filter=<?php foreach($finalvar as $fletter) : ?>".filter_<?php echo standardize($fletter); ?>">
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
                <?php if($this->field('icon#'.$i)->value()): ?><i class="<?php echo $this->field('icon#'.$i)->value(); ?>"></i><?php endif; ?>
                <span class="name"><?php if($this->field('label_items#'.$i)->value()): ?><?php echo $this->field('label_items#'.$i)->value(); ?><?php else: ?><?php echo $this->field('name#'.$i)->value(); ?><?php endif; ?>
                </span>
        </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

PHP code works but I have a problem on the HTML code. The generated HTML code is this:

```
<a data-filter=".filter_country">
            ".filter_capital;
                
    <span class="name">Australia</span>
</a>
```

My goal is to implement this one:

```
<a data-filter=".filter_country,.filter_capital"
    <span class="name">Australia</span>
</a>
```

I know it's something in front of me but I cannot see it. Does anyone have an idea concerning the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax:

```
<?php foreach ($this->group('filter') as $i => $fields) : ?>
    <?php $newField = $this->field('name#' . $i)->value(); ?>
    <?php $finalvar = explode(",", $newField); ?>
    <a data-filter="
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($finalvar as $fletter) { ?>
            .filter_<?php echo standardize($fletter); ?>
            <?php if ($i < count($fletter)) { ?>, <?php } ?>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
    ">
    <?php if ($this->field('icon#' . $i)->value()) : ?><i class="<?php echo $this->field('icon#' . $i)->value(); ?>"></i><?php endif; ?>
    <span class="name"><?php if ($this->field('label_items#' . $i)->value()) : ?><?php echo $this->field('label_items#' . $i)->value(); ?><?php else : ?><?php echo $this->field('name#' . $i)->value(); ?><?php endif; ?>
    </span>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Now the result is 

data-filter=".filter_neu-isenburg.filter_frankfurt"

I need this one 

data-filter=".filter_neu-isenburg,.filter_frankfurt" (with a comma) so it can be splitted

Comment: Just edited, missing comma

Comment: Is there any way not to use the comma in the last index of foreach? I need it only to spit the attributes

Comment: Add a check for the last element of foreach